# Python index out of range error, not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python, have done it a bit for my physics university course.

At the moment I'm trying to write a program to calculate some stuff to do with vector functions, that's not really important though as I have it all working up until the last section.

The program up to this point produces a load of local minima on a 2D graph, however I need to find the minimum value overall.

```
for i in range(100):
    pyplot.xlim(x0, x1) # x0, y0 etc are constants defined before in global scope
    pyplot.ylim(y0, y1)
    pyplot.plot(min_points[:,0], min_points[:,1])
    x, y = random.uniform(x0, x1), random.uniform(y0, y1)
    min_points = gradient_descent((x,y)) # gradient_descent is function used

    xmin_list, ymin_list = [], [] # now to find overall minima, initialise list
                                  # of local minima, and append those that are within
                                  # the boundaries
    if x0 < min_points[-1, 0] < x1:
        if y0 < min_points[-1, 1] < y1:

            xmin_list.append(min_points[-1, 0])
            ymin_list.append(min_points[-1, 1])

    xmin, ymin = xmin_list[0], ymin_list[1] # < error comes in this line
```

I've included the rest of the big for loop below for completeness, but it's not the bit giving me an error (yet).

```
    for ix in range(len(xmin_list)):
        for iy in range(len(ymin_list)):
            if f((xmin_list[ix], ymin_list[iy])) < f((xmin, ymin)):
                xmin, ymin = xmin_list[ix], ymin_list[iy]
```

So it's clearly something around the middle of the whole loop, but I'm not sure why I'm getting the error. I'm trying to access the last elements of each list, then append them to the list (after checking for fitting the conditions x0, x1 etc).

I'm not sure why it's not working..

I'm also sure this is a fairly complex way of going about finding the minimum, but it seemed logical to me, and I get confused easily having to do extra things like check they're within the boundaries etc.

Thanks for any help! And yes I'm also sure my coding looks horrible and messy, but I'll tidy it up after I get it working (they're not very good at teaching us style, only function..)

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to post the error exactly, here it is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filepath etc etc", line 67, in <module>
    xmin, ymin = xmin_list[0], ymin_list[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Have you done some debugging? Use a debugger and go through your code step by step. Inspect the variables. Then you should find the flaw...

Comment: If you want help you should at least post the stacktrace and any other relevant information (e.g. which line specifically the error comes from).

Comment: On an almost, but not quite, unrelated matter: The Python compiler should issue a warning whenever it sees `for <name> in range(len(<dotted_name>))`. Seriously. If you don't know why or how it should be written instead, you should stop writing real code right now and go back to a Python tutorial.

Comment: @Felix Kling, I'm using Pydev in Eclipse, and am not very adept at using the debugger yet, but I'm working on it. @Mark Byers and Chinmay Kanchi; yep, it would have helped, edited it for future reference. And delnan, I don't know why or how it should be written instead. I don't get any errors or warnings with it, although I understand it isn't a very elegant way of doing it. Will read up on it after I get it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xmin, ymin = xmin_list[0], ymin_list[1] # < error comes in this line
```

The error here is the `[1]`. If the preceding `if` statement conditions are `False`, then `ymin_list` is still the empty list you set it to, and index 1 is past the end.

Also, in the second part you don't need to be using `range(len())` like that.  Try:

```
xmin = xmin_list[0]
ymin = ymin_list[0]
vmin = f((xmin, ymin))
for x in xmin_list:
    for y in ymin_list:
        v = f((x, y))
        if v < vmin:
            xmin = x
            ymin = y
            vmin = v
```

... Come to think of it, are you initializing `xmin` and `ymin`?

Comment: okay I see now why the error is appearing, as you say. And thanks for the help with the second part, I've modified it now. I have initialised xmin and ymin, in the line that the error was appearing in. i'm just setting them as the values I'm trying to take from my list. EDIT: Oh thank you very much, I've got it working now. It also didn't help that I had the line with the error in outside the loop it was iterating over